# Sourcing Cached Images from Amazon S3

Tags: image-processing, amazon-s3, cdn

I'm using the S3 API to store my original images on AWS S3, but was wondering if there is an advantage of sourcing the cached, resized images (using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) if that matters) from my local disk or if I should bring these in from S3 as well. My app has a route setup so the user requests `/uploads/large/path/to/image.jpg`, but behind the scenes it grabs them from wherever it needs to. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a **trade-off** between cost, performance and flexibility.

- Your local disk can run out of space, while Amazon S3 won't run out of space
- Local EBS storage is more expensive than Amazon S3
- It would be slightly slower to retrieve the file from Amazon S3 compared to serving if from local disk storage

An alternative would be to **serve the images directly from Amazon S3** rather than from your app. This would involve returning a link that points to S3, so when the web browser retrieves the image it grabs it directly from S3. The advantage is that you will have **less traffic hitting your app**, allowing your server to handle more load. If security is a concern, you can create time-limited **pre-signed URLs** that can control access to the files.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your thoughts on this! My route is the one that actually triggers the cached image size creation, so passing a direct route to S3 wouldn't work in this situation. I think I may look into the speed differences grabbing everything from S3. Thanks again!